# Can one class have multiple categories in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c

For instance:

```
@interface ClassToAddMethodsTo (category1,category2,category3) 
  ...methods go here
@end
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A class can have multiple categories but they must be separate:

```
@interface MyClass (FirstCategory) 
...
@end

@interface MyClass (SecondCategory) 
...
@end
```

And so on.